# Why the twitter card doesn't show the image?

Tags: html, twitter, meta-tags, twitter-card

when I try to publish the link of my website on twitter  this is the result:

[image]

I tried to resize the image in every way using the most recommended sizes. right now I'm usig an image 280x150

these are my meta tags:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Title">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Description">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="www.mysite.com/immaginiArticoli/myimg.png">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="www.mysite.com">
```

Comment: Is this a [summary card](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/summary.html)? There is a validator link on that page if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've already checked that site, I followed their instruction in writing the meta tags and resizing the image but the problem remain. The validator link gives me the same result as the twitter post, that is the one in the picture in my previous comment. p.s. sorry for my bad english.

Comment: ok i solved the problem. My website did't use the ssl protocol, probably twitter doesen't show the cards of non secure website. Now the same image, but with an https url works.

Comment: The overall issue was that in your original tags you did not provide *any* protocol in the image URL. You need to provide http or https as the protocol in the URL in order for the crawler to find it.

Comment: Andy I also tried to put the full link http://www.example.com/immaginiArticoli/myimg.png and in did't work. The exact same url with httpS (after I validate the ssl certificate) works